# error: ambiguous default type conversion from ‘wxUniChar’

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm porting gspiceui to OS X which is based on wxWidgets, but it is used to run under 2.8 and on OS X 2.9 (svn) runs te best. And is made for the future. The error I get:

```
gnucap/commands/CmdGnuCapPR.cpp: In member function ‘virtual bool CmdGnuCapPR::bParse()’:
gnucap/commands/CmdGnuCapPR.cpp:177: error: ambiguous default type conversion from ‘wxUniChar’
gnucap/commands/CmdGnuCapPR.cpp:177: error:   candidate conversions include ‘wxUniChar::operator char() const’ and ‘wxUniChar::operator unsigned char()
```

But I can't figure out how to fix this peace of code:

os1 is of type wxString

file gnucap/commands/CmdGnuCapPR.cpp:

```
176       switch( os1.GetChar( 1 ) )
177       {
178         case wxT('M') : m_bCpxPrts[ eCPX_MAG   ] = TRUE; break;
179         case wxT('P') : m_bCpxPrts[ eCPX_PHASE ] = TRUE; break;
180         case wxT('R') : m_bCpxPrts[ eCPX_REAL  ] = TRUE; break;
181         case wxT('I') : m_bCpxPrts[ eCPX_IMAG  ] = TRUE; break;
182         case wxT('D') :
183           if( os1.Mid( 1, 2 ).Upper( ) == wxT("DB") )
184           {
185             m_bCpxPrts[ eCPX_MAG   ] = TRUE;
186             m_bCpxPrts[ eCPX_MAGDB ] = TRUE;
187             break;
188           }
189         default :                return( bValidate( ) );
190       }
```

The wxUniChar class is documented here:

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_uni_char.html

And wxString here:

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_string.html

Kind regards,
Jerry Jacobs

Comment: It's made for the future! How long do we have before you need an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Well, wxUniChar has two methods that could be used in the switch:

```
operator char() const
```

and

```
operator unsigned char () const
```

both `char` and `unsigned char` are valid types for the switch, so the compiler needs you to specify which one to use. So to solve the problem, just cast `os1.GetChar( 1 )` to either `char` or `unsigned char`.

**Late addition:**

`wxT()`, used in the cases, converts to either a `char` or a `wchar_t`, depending on the build type (ANSI/Unicode). If you're using a Unicode build, you should actually cast the switch value to a `wchar_t` and not one of the ANSI chars. This might make your code less portable in terms of ANSI/Unicode builds, but is shouldn't be that much of a problem to solve.

Comment: Agreed; and I'd suggest `unsigned char` so that you can use the full range of values. If it's a "unicode char" the implication may be that the high bit is likely to be used; at the very least, you're never going to want a negative value.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal, I'm not sure this is correct. The cases use chars. If, theoretically, one of the cases was a non-ASCII char, its value would have been a negative number. However, casting that non-ASCII char in the switch to an unsigned value would have given a number larger than 127. And as for Unicode, please see my late addition to the answer (it won't matter for ASCII chars, but it will for others).

Comment: If it were a non-ASCII char, then that's a number between 128-255, not a negative number. If it appeared as a negative value, that's only because you were using a signed type when you shouldn't have in the first place. The values are still equivalent (actually, the `unsigned`->`negative signed` conversion is technically implementation-defined [4.7/3] in C++0x FDIS), so your observation is not relevant.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal but chars are signed. Are you saying they shouldn't be used? (BTW, it's worth mentioning I've never worked with wxWidgets - I refer to the C++ part of it. If I'm missing a feature of the framework, that would be the reason...).

Comment: "chars are signed" according to whom? In fact, `char` is a distinct type from `unsigned char` and `signed char`, and it has implementation-defined signedness. But _it doesn't matter_; the values are the same. They are converted properly between unsigned and signed target types. I don't see why physical signedness is relevant in the slightest, aside from in my suggestion that `unsigned char` makes the most sense to a human because you think of character codes being [0-254], not [-128,127].

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal My bad. Have mostly been using VS, and the other option had never occurred to me. Thanks for the correction. But anyway, `wxT('x')` returns a char, whether on the current implementation it's signed or not. So why shouldn't the switch be on the same type?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `os1.GetChar(1)` returns a value of type `wxUniChar`, but the `switch` statement requires primitive data types to work and it doesn't know what to convert the `wxUniChar` to.

Casting to an appropriate data type should work.

`switch( static_cast<char>(os1.GetChar(1))`

Comment: Casting to wxChar seems to be the best, because it depends if you build ANSI or unicode. Then it is substituted underwater to the right data type. Char or wchar_t:

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.9.1/overview_unicode.html